# How do I get rid of these white spaces between my images and tables?

Tags: html, css

Here's my live sandbox page I'm working in: https://www.wingsfund.com/test1.html I'm trying to stack images and tables to make it look like this: https://www.wingsfund.com/ But why are those white spaces spreading it out vertically? How do i get all the elements to stack and like stick together?

```
<table width="1000" height="55" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="200" ><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/HOME-BLUE.jpg" width="200" height="55" alt=""/></td>
      <td width="200" ><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg" width="200" height="55"  onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout ="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg'" border="0" /></a><a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a></td>
      <td width="200" ><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg" width="200" height="55"  onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout ="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg'" border="0" /></a><a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a></td>
      <td width="200" ><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg" width="200" height="55"  onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout ="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg'" border="0" /></a><a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a></td>
      <td width="200" ><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg" width="200" height="55"  onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout ="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg'" border="0" /></a><a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
    <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/blue-strip.jpg" display: "block" width="1000" height="20" line-height= "0"; alt=""/></center>
<center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/banner.jpg" width="1000" height="565" line-height= "0"; alt=""/></center>
<table background="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/gray-bar.jpg" width="1000" height="92" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
```

Comment: You might consider adding the name of the tool you used to make that markup. That way others that are having this issue can find it easier.

Answer (score 1):

They used a tr and then put a background on that tr, so the whole td is filled and no white spaces are shown.

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="11" style="background-image:url(wp-..........>
    </td>
</tr>
```

What you did was totally different.
I was going to tell you to check your padding and margin, but it seems that they both are set to 0px. But the  tag is giving you those white spaces, but I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

but so far I looked at the HTML source and as per my experience, I don't think using tables is good html practice. It will be much easier to leave the elements as they are and use display: block or display: inline-block but for the most part make good use of margin: auto.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set correctly `display: block` on `style` property.

```
<center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/blue-strip.jpg" style="display: block"></center>
```

Or you can simply set css globally instead of setting css on every elements.

```css
img {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test1</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/wings-background-color.jpg" background-repeat:="" no-repeat;="">
  <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="17" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <p><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/wingsfund-1000.jpg" width="350" height="60" alt=""><br>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" height="55" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/HOME-BLUE.jpg" width="200" height="55" alt=""></td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/blue-strip.jpg" display:="" "block"="" width="1000" height="20" line-height="0" ;="" alt=""></center>
  <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/banner.jpg" width="1000" height="565" line-height="0" ;="" alt=""></center>
  <table background="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/gray-bar.jpg" width="1000" height="92" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family: arial; text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">Wings Fund, Inc. is a private investment company that concentrates on early stage companies with breakthrough technologies.<br> We also help fund acquisitions for our portfolio companies.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#E5C200">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;">Copyright © Wings Fund, Inc. 2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
          <p><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/wingsfund-1000.jpg" width="350" height="60" alt=""><br>
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" height="55" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="display: block;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td width="200"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/HOME-BLUE.jpg" width="200" height="55" alt=""></td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/what-we-seek.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/our-approach.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/public-market.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
        <td width="200">
          <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_self"><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg" width="200" height="55" onmouseover="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us-mouse.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='http://wingsfund.com/imgs/about-us.jpg'" border="0"></a>
          <a href="/what-we-seek.html"></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/blue-strip.jpg" width="1000" height="20" line-height="0" ;="" alt="" style="display: block;"></center>
  <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/banner.jpg" width="1000" height="565" line-height="0" ;="" alt=""></center>
  <table background="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/gray-bar.jpg" width="1000" height="92" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-family: arial; text-align: center; font-size: 14px;">Wings Fund, Inc. is a private investment company that concentrates on early stage companies with breakthrough technologies.<br> We also help fund acquisitions for our portfolio companies.</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#E5C200">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <table width="1000" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="30" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;">Copyright © Wings Fund, Inc. 2019</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

use display block property in table

```
   <table width="1000" height="55" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" 
   cellspacing="0" style="display: block;">
```

and in image as well

```
  <center><img src="http://wingsfund.com/imgs/blue-strip.jpg" width="1000" height="20" line-height="0" ;="" alt="" style="display: block;"></center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the line-height property set globally.
Add this to your HTML (preferably in the head):

```html
<style type="text/css">
  html {
    line-height: 0;
  }  
</style>
```